# Tint image in UISegmentedControl for selected index

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` with three images.

When the **value of the control changes** I want to **recolor the icon of the selected segment**. I know it's possible for text but I haven't found an option to change the tint color for a segmented control which consists of images instead of text titles.

How it appears:
[image]

How it should appear:
[image]

---

Icons used in the images above can be obtained here: [icons8.com](http://icons8.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While setting your image use:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"xyz.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
```

**Swift:**

```
let image = UIImage(named:"xyz.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
```

Then you can set tint color.

Comment: You can also set the rendering mode in the xcassets file.

Comment: Your answer still does not tell how to tell tint color. You told to send rendering mode. But what after that?

Comment: For me, .alwaysTemplate didn't work, but `renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal` did

Answer (score 1):

change tintcolor won't change the image's color in selected segment here. But you can directly change the segment's image when it is selected

```
func setImage(_ image: UIImage?, forSegmentAtIndex segment: Int)
```

and use always original rendering mode UIImage